# How to get all Wikipedia pages from category with title and primary image?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki-api, wikimedia

I want to list all pages from category with the title and primary image.

My current API url is this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&cmlimit=100&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AAmerican%20male%20film%20actors

with this results:

```
....
{
    "pageid": 3600962,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Lee Aaker"
},
....
```

I don't know the right parameters to get a response like this:

```
{
   "pageid": 3600962,
   "ns": 0,
   "title": "Lee Aaker",
   "thumbnail": {
       "original": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/some_image_path.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to refer the documentation of wiki https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using [categorymembers](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcategorymembers) in combination with [pageimages](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageimages):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmlimit=100&gcmtitle=Category:American male film actors&prop=pageimages&pilimit=100
```

- **categorymembers** parameters: `gcmtitle=Category:American male film actors`, `gcmlimit=100`
- **pageimages** parameters: `pilimit=100`